# Question regarding subdomains and rerouting into domain, using Flask/Nginx on Ubuntu Linode

Tags: nginx

I currently have a problem regarding my nginx configuration. I bought a domain name and set up a Linode Compute Instance. It's a simple microblog, which uses Flask/Nginx/Gunicorn/Supervisor. Now, the site is running as intended when I have the gunicorn workers going at it, serving (an example, for privacy) "domain.com". But upon navigating to "www.domain.com" (what I assume to be a subdomain), nginx just says "500 error". I managed to get a hold of the logs, and this is what's being displayed around the time of the 500 error:

```
rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 2603:7000:a700:cc1:c867:5aae:ff32:199c, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.com"
```

Now, some research on SO and Nginx docs suggest a number of reasons, while the latter also has a laundry list of what NOT to do. I'd like to approach this in the proper way. Any and all help is appreciated, and I'll also post my most current (and working) nginx configuration for the site in question below:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I'll admit I don't want to toy around with the config too much because of the LE configuration, but what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the letsencrypt cert is include `*.mydomain.com` or not?

Comment: yes, i managed to get both main and subdomain certified with an --expand command with certbot. the 500 error is secure, just isnt outputting content of the page